# Questions missed in corresponding lists of questions

Tags: support, voting, historical-lock

While watching the [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) or [XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode) tagged list of questions, I would have expected to find the question

- [Hidden Features of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/hidden-features-of-xcode)

with currently 338 upvotes between questions with nearest votes but it is not there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is it a bug which should be corrected?

Updated:
The point is that I am (as novice) would like to get the most vibrant and important topics... and they are not representative by corresponding lists....

Answer (score 1):

From [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

> Historically-locked questions are omitted from normal question lists (those on the home page, /questions, and the various per-tag lists), but can still be found by searching for words in the post or title (via either site-search or Google, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The problem we had is that this *isn't* a particularly vibrant or important question, in spite of the votes. You observed this problem in [your other recent question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271782/may-i-repeat-the-same-question-as-one-locked-with-historical-lock) here: answers become outdated, and the votes no longer reflect anything useful.

Indeed, the reason that question (and its answer) *have* so many votes is that it was essentially a poll: voting doesn't reflect usefulness so much as it does relative popularity, for a relatively brief period of time. As the question ages, we observed that it was less and less likely for answers to be maintained, and almost impossible for new answers - no matter how useful - to even make it to the first *page*.

I strongly recommend moving those answers you find useful into [the xcode tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info), where they can be more easily vetted and maintained. Once done, the poll question can be removed entirely.