# May I repeat the same question as one locked with historical lock?

Tags: discussion, support, historical-lock, rules

May I duplicate the same question as the existing one but having outdated answers and locked by [a historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)?
namely, the one cited in my question: [Questions missed in corresponding lists of questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271780/questions-missed-in-corresponding-lists-of-questions)

Comment: Tell us what is outdated, and we'll fix it on the original question (if it's worth doing so).

Answer (score 5):

No. Questions with a historical lock are under such protection to prevent them being deleted. They are otherwise *off topic* and not appropriate anymore for Stack Overflow.

As the message on such a post states:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.

If you post the same question now, it'll be closed as off-topic outright. If the answers to the existing question are obsolete and hence worthless, you can raise the issue here and suggest that it be removed.

Comment: Sometimes outdated is very much not worthless.

Comment: @Deduplicator: in which case a meta discussion can work that out.